# How to add row ordering feature(row drag and drop) to free version of x-data-grid component of MaterialUI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable, mui-x-data-grid

I've been trying to make my x-data-grid component row orderable but I failed. The code below shows rows but they are not draggable. Here is the code that is not working for me.

```
<DragDropContext onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}>
    <Droppable droppableId="rows">
        {(provided, snapshot) => (
            <div ref={provided.innerRef} {...provided.droppableProps}>
                <DataGrid
                    rows={rows}
                    columns={columns}
                    components={{
                        Row: ({ index, style, ...rest }) => (
                            <Draggable draggableId={index.toString()} index={index}>
                                {(provided, snapshot) => {
                                    return <div
                                             ref={provided.innerRef}
                                             {...provided.draggableProps}
                                             {...provided.dragHandleProps}>
                                              <GridRow {...rest} />
                                            </div>
                                 }}
                             </Draggable>
                             ),
                      }}
                   />
                {provided.placeholder}
           </div>
       )}
    </Droppable>
</DragDropContext>
```

Can you please say if it is possible or not? If it is, please explain it.

Comment: I solved almost all my problems with x-data-grid by switching another library called ["material-react-table"](https://www.material-react-table.com/). It uses materialUI components and @tanstack/react-table, provides most of the premium features of x-data-grdi and completely free.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using `@use-gesture/react` instead of the less flexible `react-beautiful-dnd` it seems like you're using. This does involve creating your own logic for dragging, however:

```js
import { useDrag } from '@use-gesture/react';

const DraggableRow = (props) => {
  const ref = useRef(null);

  useDrag(({ values, last, target }) => {
    const rowBeingDragged = target.closest(`[data-rowindex]`);

    const [x, y] = values;
    const immediateElem = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);

    const rowDraggedOver = immediateElem?.closest(`[data-rowindex]`);
    if (!rowDraggedOver || !rowBeingDragged) return;

    // Your dragging logic here.....

    if (last) {
      // Your drag end logic here.....
    }
  }, {target: ref});

  return <GridRow style={{ userSelect: 'none', touchAction: 'none' }} ref={ref} {...props} />;
}
```

Then used on the components object like you have above:

```js
...
components={{
  Row: DraggableRow
}}
...
```

It's worth noting that this approach won't allow for scrolling the datagrid on mobile, as it's the same action for dragging & scrolling.